# python constant decorator not taking in self when applied to a function

Tags: python

I made a constant decorated that looks like this

```
def constant(f):
  def fset(self, value):
    raise TypeError
  @wraps(f)
  def fget(self):
    return f()
  return property(fget, fset)
```

but when I use it on a function and call it, I get thrown a type error for not passing in enough arguments, I thought adding in the wraps decorator would solve this but it didn't.

```
class IrrigationAmount(AbstractCalculation):

    def __init__(self, wvf, fc):
        self._wvf = float(wvf)
        self._fc = float(fc)
        self._value = 0

    def calculate(self):
        self._value = (self.fc*SECTORVOLUME - self.wvf*SECTORVOLUME)/FLOWRATE

    @constant
    def value(self):
        return self._value
```

Here's how I tested it, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, mainly why self isn't being passed in automatically due to the wraps. I probably misunderstood what wraps does terribly.

```
    >>> from irrigationservice.irrigation import IrrigationAmount
>>> a = IrrigationAmount(0.12, 0.2)
>>> a.calculate()
>>> a.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/krishna/Documents/irrigationwebserver/webserver/irrigationservice/utils.py", line 12, in fget
    return f()
TypeError: value() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: can you use a.value()

Comment: @Shrey no same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to replace the constant function definition and the @constant decorator with something like this:

```
@property
def value(self):
    """return the protected value"""
    return self._value
```

EDIT: add the following example to address some comments

Create file myvalue.py...

```
class MyValue:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._value = 0

    def calculate(self):
        self._value = self._x*self._y

    @property
    def value(self):
        """return the protected value"""
        return self._value
```

Now run in python:

```
>>> from myvalue import MyValue
>>> z = MyValue(2, 3)
>>> z.value
0
>>> z.calculate()
>>> z.value
6
>>> z.value = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: No then it would still allow me to set value and will not throw an error

Comment: @jacksexton: No it won't, unless you explicitly decorate another function with `@value.setter`.

Answer (score 2):

While [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34013313/364696) is the right way to do this (you don't need a special `@constant` decorator when `@property` is naturally read-only unless you explicitly decorate other methods with `@propname.setter`), the reason you have the problem is that the decorated class method isn't bound, and you're not explicitly passing `self` to it.

Change the code to:

```
def fget(self):
    return f(self)
```

so the `self` argument actually goes where it's supposed to.

Comment: But seriously, just replace uses of `@constant` with `@property`; the only difference in behavior is that attempting to set an `@property` without a `.setter` raises `AttributeError: can't set attribute`, not `TypeError`.